# After git rebase, my pull request contains some commits not made by me

Tags: git, rebase

I have branch A and branch B.
I made a pull request from branch B to branch A.

Branch A moved and had new changes after that. So, I did `git pull origin` on branch A and after that I performed a rebase on branch B.

I did `git push --force` after that. However, after this my pull request shows the commits that I did not make. And my commits appear after that.

Those commits that I did not make are already on branch A (they are new commits that was made after I opened my PR), and I want to clean up my commit history on PR. How can I do that?

Comment: Is the branch you are wanting to merge into set correctly?

Comment: It's typically bad practice to change the history (rebase) a branch that has been shared (pushed to a remote). When you're tempted to use `--force`, think hard about it...and then don't do it. That said, it sounds like your PR is still based off the original branch A. You might try opening a new one and see if that fixes things.

Comment: When you want to merge B->A, then you should rebase B on A, not the other way round. You probably duplicated all commits of A onto your branch B. Use `gitk` or `git log --format=fuller` to check if the commits have you as committer, but somebody else as author. Also, check their commit hashes.